# HTML5/CSS3 User Text Resize

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an accessibility option to a website, where you can click some buttons ' A A A ' and these would change the size of the text on the whole site, using HTML5 and CSS3 only. I don't want to use jQuery or Javascript to do it.

Based on this idea: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/textsizer.htm

Any help would be great!

Comment: Not possible without JS (unless the buttons are physical links to another page, but that is bad from usability, SEO and maintainability standpoints).  However this would be really simple JS assuming your CSS is structured well and uses relative sizing (e.g. `ems`).  Basically you'd just add a class to the `body` like `text-large` or `text-small` and change the base `em` value.

Comment: I see you've been a member for 11 months, but you might benefit from [reading about how to write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There is nothing wrong with conceptual programming questions, but if you don't have a _specific_ question it might be better suited to [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: First, what have you tried?  Second, I hate to bring up the beast but....if you are concerned with accessibility, surely you are also concerned with cross-browser compatibility as well.  You'll definitely want fallbacks for older versions of IE that do not recognize any HTML5 or CSS3 elements.  jQuery text resizing is simple AND would be compatible with older browsers.  A certain demographic that would need larger text is older people, who very much tend to have very old versions of IE, just sayin. :)

Comment: Thanks for all your comments regarding this, ill take it back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do it like this:

```
    #element{
      font-size:12px;
    }


    #element:click{
      font-size:14px;
      -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
      -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
      -o-transition: all 1s linear;
      transition: all 1s linear;
    }
```